# Bingo in Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Say I have a matrix

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
              [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
              [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

I want to check if an 1D array is included in this matrix horizontally, vertically or (anti)diagonally. Below is the code that I came up with

```
def bingo(a, A):
    return np.max(np.diff(np.argwhere(np.isin(A, a)).T))

a1 = np.array([3, 4])         # horizontal
a2 = np.array([1, 5, 9])      # vertical
a3 = np.array([5, 10, 15])    # diagonal
a4 = np.array([13, 10, 7, 4]) # anti-diagonal
assert bingo(a1, A) == bingo(a2, A) == bingo(a3, A) == bingo(a4, A) == True
```

However, there are 3 major issues with my code:

1. I don't want to consider the reverse case, which my code does. For example, `np.array([4, 3, 2, 1])` should not be considered as being included in the matrix `A`.
2. My code won't work if the array only contains 1 element. For example, `np.array([1])` should be considered as being included in the matrix `A`.
3. My code won't work if the matrix `A` contains duplicate elements.

Can anyone suggest a general and numpyic way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I don't think there's a solution without two loops here. Here's what I've came up with:

```
def get_diagonal(matrix, pos, length):
     diag = []
     for i in range(min(length, matrix.shape[0] - pos[0], matrix.shape[1] - pos[1])):
         diag.append(matrix[pos[0] + i, pos[1] + i])
     return diag

 def bingo(matrix, array):
     for x_pos in range(matrix.shape[1]):
         for y_pos in range(matrix.shape[0]):
             if all(matrix[y_pos : min(len(array)+y_pos, y_pos+matrix.shape[0]), x_pos] == array) and (matrix.shape[0] - y_pos) >= len(array):
                 print('vertical bingo')
             if all(matrix[y_pos, x_pos : min(len(array)+x_pos, x_pos+matrix.shape[1])] == array) and (matrix.shape[1] - x_pos) >= len(array):
                 print('horizonthal bingo')
             diag = get_diagonal(matrix, (y_pos, x_pos), len(array))
             if all(diag == array) and (len(diag) >= len(array)):
                 print('diagonal bingo')

>>> matrix = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> bingo(matrix, np.array([5,6]))
horizonthal bingo
>>> bingo(matrix, np.array([5,9]))
diagonal bingo
```

Comment: What about anti-diagonal (from lower left to upper right)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to test the rows, the columns and the two diagonals.

All individual cases are easy to perform, you can then combine them with `or` to have lazy evaluation (i.e., evaluation stops as soon as one match is found):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
              [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
              [13, 14, 15, 16]])

def bingo(A, test):
    return (# rows
            (A == test).all(1).any()
            # cols
            or (A.T == test).all(1).any()
            # first diagonal
            or (test == A.diagonal()).all()
            # second diagonal
            or (test == np.fliplr(A.T).diagonal()).all()
            )

bingo(A, [1,2,3,4])    # True

bingo(A, [1,2,4,3])    # False

bingo(A, [2,6,10,14])  # True

bingo(A, [4,3,2,1])    # False 

bingo(A, [1,6,11,16])  # True

bingo(A, [13,10,7,4])  # True
```

Comment: I just tested your code with `[1, 2, 6]` and I get `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for the first two cases

```
def bingo(a, A):
    if len(a)==1:
        return a in A
    positions = np.argwhere(np.isin(A, a))
    not_reversed = A[positions[0,0],positions[0,1]] == a[0]
    return np.max(np.diff( positions.T )) * not_reversed
```

However your use of max may not be foolproof. For example f = np.array([ 1,  2,  6 ]) will be considered as being in A.
I'm starting to wonder if the simplest solutions wouldn't be to check for array length, and then check column by column, line by line and diagonal by diagonal...